# Jquery plugin help...need to add my own functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to add my own functionality to a jQuery plugin and to be honest it is not going well, I am using the easySlider 1.7 from [here](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider)

My idea is to use the paginated version, there is an example on the linked site above, but instead pausing when the user clicks on one the numbered links, I want it to skip to that slide hold and then carry on. Below is my attempt, I will post the whole plugin and comment around the bits I understand and the bits I have added.

```
          /*
         *  Easy Slider 1.7 - jQuery plugin
         *  written by Alen Grakalic    
         *  http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding
         *
         *  Copyright (c) 2009 Alen Grakalic (http://cssglobe.com)
         *  Dual licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt)
         *  and GPL (GPL-LICENSE.txt) licenses.
         *
         *  Built for jQuery library
         *  http://jquery.com
         *
         */

        /*
         *  markup example for $("#slider").easySlider();
         *  
         *  <div id="slider">
         *      <ul>
         *          <li><img src="images/01.jpg" alt="" /></li>
         *          <li><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="" /></li>
         *          <li><img src="images/03.jpg" alt="" /></li>
         *          <li><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="" /></li>
         *          <li><img src="images/05.jpg" alt="" /></li>
         *      </ul>
         *  </div>
         *
         */

        (function($) {

            $.fn.easySlider = function(options){

                // default configuration properties
                var defaults = {            
                    prevId:         'prevBtn',
                    prevText:       'Previous',
                    nextId:         'nextBtn',  
                    nextText:       'Next',
                    controlsShow:   true,
                    controlsBefore: '',
                    controlsAfter:  '', 
                    controlsFade:   true,
                    firstId:        'firstBtn',
                    firstText:      'First',
                    firstShow:      false,
                    lastId:         'lastBtn',  
                    lastText:       'Last',
                    lastShow:       false,              
                    vertical:       false,
                    speed:          800,
                    auto:           false,
                    pause:          2000,
                    continuous:     false, 
                    numeric:        false,
                    numericId:      'controls'
                }; 

                var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

                this.each(function() {  
                    var obj = $(this);              
                    var s = $("li", obj).length;
                    var w = $("li", obj).width(); 
                    var h = $("li", obj).height(); 
                    var clickable = true;
                    obj.width(w); 
                    obj.height(h); 
                    obj.css("overflow","hidden");
                    var ts = s-1;
                    var t = 0;
                    $("ul", obj).css('width',s*w);          

                    if(options.continuous){
                        $("ul", obj).prepend($("ul li:last-child", obj).clone().css("margin-left","-"+ w +"px"));
                        $("ul", obj).append($("ul li:nth-child(2)", obj).clone());
                        $("ul", obj).css('width',(s+1)*w);
                    };              

                    if(!options.vertical) $("li", obj).css('float','left');

                    if(options.controlsShow){
                        var html = options.controlsBefore;              
                        if(options.numeric){
                            html += '<ol id="'+ options.numericId +'"></ol>';
                        } else {
                            if(options.firstShow) html += '<span id="'+ options.firstId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.firstText +'</a></span>';
                            html += ' <span id="'+ options.prevId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.prevText +'</a></span>';
                            html += ' <span id="'+ options.nextId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.nextText +'</a></span>';
                            if(options.lastShow) html += ' <span id="'+ options.lastId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.lastText +'</a></span>';              
                        };

                        html += options.controlsAfter;                      
                        $(obj).after(html);                                     
                    };
    /**************************
    This section creates the numbered list that the user can click, clicking a numbered link pauses the slider
    *******************/    
        if(options.numeric){                                    
                        for(var i=0;i<s;i++){                       
                            $(document.createElement("li"))
                                .attr('id',options.numericId + (i+1))
                                .html('<a rel='+ i +' href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ (i+1) +'</a>')
                                .appendTo($("#"+ options.numericId))
                                .click(function(){                          
                                    animate($("a",$(this)).attr('rel'),true);
                                });                                                 
                        };                          
                    } else {
                        $("a","#"+options.nextId).click(function(){     
                            animate("next",true);
                        });
                        $("a","#"+options.prevId).click(function(){     
                            animate("prev",true);               
                        }); 
                        $("a","#"+options.firstId).click(function(){        
                            animate("first",true);
                        });             
                        $("a","#"+options.lastId).click(function(){     
                            animate("last",true);               
                        });             
                    };
/*The following code is my attempt to play and pause, the first created element is meant to stop the animation, but it just send it back to the first slide, the second created element, takes it to the second slide, I was hope one would pause and the other would play from the current slide****/
                    $(document.createElement("a"))
                        .attr('id', 'stop')
                        .html('<a>S</a>')
                        .appendTo($("#"+ options.numericId))
                        .click(function(){                          
                            //animate("first", true)
                            alert(defaults.continuous)
                            alert(defaults.auto)
                            animate(false)
                        });

                        $(document.createElement("a"))
                            .attr('id', 'stop')
                            .html('<a>P</a>')
                            .appendTo($("#"+ options.numericId))
                            .click(function(){                          
                                //animate("first", true)
                                alert(defaults.continuous)
                                alert(defaults.auto)
                                animate(true)
                            });

                    function setCurrent(i){
                        i = parseInt(i)+1;
                        $("li", "#" + options.numericId).removeClass("current");
                        $("li#" + options.numericId + i).addClass("current");
                    };

                    function adjust(){
                        if(t>ts) t=0;       
                        if(t<0) t=ts;   
                        if(!options.vertical) {
                            $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*w*-1));
                        } else {
                            $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*h*-1));
                        }
                        clickable = true;
                        if(options.numeric) setCurrent(t);
                    };

                    function animate(dir,clicked){
                        if (clickable){
                            clickable = false;
                            var ot = t;             
                            switch(dir){
                                case "next":
                                    t = (ot>=ts) ? (options.continuous ? t+1 : ts) : t+1;                       
                                    break; 
                                case "prev":
                                    t = (t<=0) ? (options.continuous ? t-1 : 0) : t-1;
                                    break; 
                                case "first":
                                    t = 0;
                                    break; 
                                case "last":
                                    t = ts;
                                    break; 
                                default:
                                    t = dir;
                                    break; 
                            };  
                            var diff = Math.abs(ot-t);
                            var speed = diff*options.speed;                     
                            if(!options.vertical) {
                                p = (t*w*-1);
                                $("ul",obj).animate(
                                    { marginLeft: p }, 
                                    { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
                                );              
                            } else {
                                p = (t*h*-1);
                                $("ul",obj).animate(
                                    { marginTop: p }, 
                                    { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
                                );                  
                            };

                            if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){                    
                                if(t==ts){
                                    $("a","#"+options.nextId).hide();
                                    $("a","#"+options.lastId).hide();
                                } else {
                                    $("a","#"+options.nextId).show();
                                    $("a","#"+options.lastId).show();                   
                                };
                                if(t==0){
                                    $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
                                    $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();
                                } else {
                                    $("a","#"+options.prevId).show();
                                    $("a","#"+options.firstId).show();
                                };                  
                            };              

                            if(clicked) clearTimeout(timeout);
                            if(options.auto && dir=="next" && !clicked){;
                                timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                                    animate("next",false);
                                },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
                            };

                        };

                    };
                    // init
                    var timeout;
                    if(options.auto){;
                        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                            animate("next",false);
                        },options.pause);
                    };      

                    if(options.numeric) setCurrent(0);

                    if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){                    
                        $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
                        $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();              
                    };              

                });

            };

        })(jQuery);
```

It is pretty obvious that I am way off in my attemp, I would be really greatful if someone could give me a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hover listener for either the links or for the whole element passed in to the slider, and when the user clicks or hovers, you can clear the auto advance timeout. When they leave, you can set the timeout up again and continue on.

Something like this would work on the whole element:

```
obj.hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}, function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        animate("next",false);
    }, 2000);
});
```

You could put that at around line 211, and it should work. Is that what you were looking for? Or do you want it to only pause after they have clicked a link, and then wait for them to leave the links?

If that is the case, you could use the above code, but with a couple changes:

1. Get rid of the first "clearTimeout(timeout);" so that it won't pause when you hover over the slider.
2. Add a global variable by changing "var timeout;" to "var timeout, linkClickPausedSlider;".
3. In the "animate" function, set linkClickPausedSlider = clicked.
4. Change the code I gave you to only setTimeout when the user hovers out if linkClickPausedSlider == true, and to set linkClickPausedSlider to false when you do set the timeout.

There... that should be an exhaustive answer. Hope this helps you. Happy jQuerying!